# Send Delphi Record via Socket to C#

Tags: c#, sockets, delphi, marshalling

as the topic mentions I try to send a Delphi record via a socket to C# and try to marhsal it as a struct.

IDE: XE7 and MS Visual Stidio 2010

```
Type Data = record 
intDiscipline:         Integer;
intNumberOfSets:       Integer;
strPlayer1ID:          string[50];
strPlayer2ID:          string[50];
strPlayer3ID:          string[50];
strPlayer4ID:          string[50];
strPlayer1Name:        string[50];
strPlayer2Name:        string[50];
strPlayer3Name:        string[50];
strPlayer4Name:        string[50];
intTournamentProgress: Integer;
intTableNumber:        Integer;
end;
```

The C# struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
    public struct structTiFuRecord
    {
        public int intDiscipline;
        public int intNumberOfSets;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
        public string strPlayer1ID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
        public string strPlayer2ID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
        public string strPlayer3ID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
        public string strPlayer4ID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
        public string strPlayer1Name;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
        public string strPlayer2Name;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
        public string strPlayer3Name;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
        public string strPlayer4Name;
        public int intTournamentProgress;
        public int intTableNumber;
    }
```

This is the Delphi record being sent with this code:

```
IdTCPClient1.Connect;

Data.intDiscipline := 1;
Data.intNumberOfSets := 5;
Data.strPlayer1ID := 'Detlef';
Data.strPlayer2ID := 'Test';
Data.strPlayer3ID := 'Test';
Data.strPlayer4ID := 'Test';
Data.strPlayer1Name := 'Test';
Data.strPlayer2Name := 'Test';
Data.strPlayer3Name := 'Test';
Data.strPlayer4Name := 'Test';
Data.intTournamentProgress := 99;
Data.intTableNumber := 1;

networkHeaderRecord.intFlag := 1;
networkHeaderRecord.intPayload := SizeOf(TiFuRecord);
networkHeaderRecord.intPacketnumber := 1;

Buffer := RawToBytes(networkHeaderRecord, SizeOf(networkHeaderRecord));
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(Buffer);

Buffer := RawToBytes(TiFuRecord, SizeOf(TiFuRecord));
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(Buffer);
```

Size Of the Record is 424 Bytes. These are being send.
In C# (sorry the code was just for testing - it smells ;-( but as their are only 3-4 lines should be fine - hope so)

```
byte[] arrHeader = new byte[intHeaderLength];

            networkStream.Read(arrHeader, 0, intHeaderLength);

            phReceive = new ProtocolHeader(arrHeader);

            byte[] testArr = new byte[phReceive.Payload];

            networkStream.Read(testArr, 0, (int)phReceive.Payload);

            test2 = (HelperClass.structTiFuRecord)ByteArrayToStructure(testArr, TiFuRecord, 0);
```

And last but not least here is the code of the function to marshal the byte array:

```
public static object ByteArrayToStructure(byte[] bytearray, object structureObj, int position)
    {
        int length = Marshal.SizeOf(structureObj);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
        Marshal.Copy(bytearray, 0, ptr, length);
        structureObj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(bytearray, position), structureObj.GetType());
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return structureObj;
    }
```

I am pretty close to a good result. For the integers in the beginning the values are correct. But already the first string is wrong and from their it snowballs. I checked the size the record being send 424 bytes and the struct in c# where I do marshal.sizeOf(struct) ==> 416 bytes. They don't match regarding their size. I assume the size for the strings is wrong. I tried several different ways to socket write on delphi side and also from different posts from here to change the c# struct. Pack param, layout etc.

Support appreciated. Many thanks and best,
Mäfinho

Comment: IMO, this is why we have protocols like SOAP and JSON.  If you have control over both applications, you should seriously look at re-architecting this.

Comment: Thanks, but infact I don't develop both applications...

Otherwise I probably won't mix developing languages.

Anyways. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It so happens that the Delphi record has no padding, irrespective of compiler settings. But to match the C# code you should declare the record to be `packed`.

```
type 
  Data = packed record  
    ....
  end;
```

The 8 bytes difference is due to the Delphi short strings having a length byte prefix. You have 8 strings, and are missing 8 single byte length prefixes. Declare that for each string in your C# code and all will be well.

So to be clear, the `string[50]` variables all have size 51. They are laid out with a single byte containing the length, and then 50 8 bit character elements. The C# to match your Delphi would look like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct structTiFuRecord
{
    public int intDiscipline;

    public int intNumberOfSets;

    public byte strPlayer1IDlen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
    public string strPlayer1ID;

    public byte strPlayer2IDlen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
    public string strPlayer2ID;

    public byte strPlayer3IDlen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
    public string strPlayer3ID;

    public byte strPlayer4IDlen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
    public string strPlayer4ID;

    public byte strPlayer1Namelen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
    public string strPlayer1Name;

    public byte strPlayer2Namelen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
    public string strPlayer2Name;

    public byte strPlayer3Namelen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
    public string strPlayer3Name;

    public byte strPlayer4Namelen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
    public string strPlayer4Name;

    public int intTournamentProgress;

    public int intTableNumber;
}
```

On a broader level, your approach ignores endianness issues, and is quite brittle, as you have discovered. Your use of short strings condemns you to ASCII or perhaps ANSI code pages, although the latter requires that both machines use the same code page.

Consider serializing this data as a JSON object, say, to avoid such issues.

Comment: Hey,
Thank you for you Comment!

I fixed exactly what you wrote my self because I missed your post. Anyways many thanks! Regarding JSON still one last question. Due to the fact that endianess is only related to integers this issue would be solved - never the less Delphi -> C# would require that I delete or add (depends on sending direction) the null termination, right? Is there a professional way to deal with this? It seems not elegant to me to delete the last byte/char of a string or to add it.

Further could I not still encounter problems regarding Encoding?When sending a String via network?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand that comment. I don't see JSON and null termination as an issue. Right off the bat you'd stop using short strings and just use native language strings. Encoding? UTF-8. As for endianness, it applies to 16 and 32 bit character elements also, as well as floating point types.

Comment: I would like to exchange the JSON string via the socket. First of all no need for any webservice online and on top it is not mandatory for the client to be online to exchange the data.

Comment: Well that should be just fine

Comment: but I still got one problem...I just realize now. If I want to send the json string via the socket I need to determine the size. As it can differ I need to send some header information what size the next incoming data will have, right? Then I am back (when using a header) to a header packet with probably integer ==> endian problem

Any smart idea?

Comment: Endian problem is not a difficult problem. Just convert from host to network when you send and network to host when you receive.

Comment: How am I able to send this JSON string via the socket correctly? I assumed that I need on Delphi part a record containing one string, the json result. Your advice was a UTF8 string. Ok, when I send this record like I do with the header via the Buffer what needs to be the exact struct on the C# side? Charset.UTF8 is no option for a C# struct. Further how get I rid of the problem to set the const size on side of C# for the struct? Also that it won't be probably always the same size.

Comment: The struct needs to be serialized (and later deserialized) to JSON. Send that JSON over the socket.